# You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have created a new MVC application with windows authentication and without doing any changes to application, I have deployed to Azure App Service.

When I browse the  URL I am getting the message as "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.".

When I check the "DetailedErrors" folder, it was "IIS Detailed Error - 401.0 - Unauthorized".

I have referred many post with this issue. But none of the solution mentioned in the post solved my issue.

Please let me know what configuration I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication is not supported in App Service.
In order for IWA to work, the server would need to be AD joined. 
You do not have that level of access in App Service.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/moving-legacy-asp-net-apps-with-windows-authentication-to-azure-app-service-part-1/

You will have to migrate to e.g. Azure AD authentication or host the app on a platform that supports IWA.